# How to override a Magento administration panel?

Tags: magento, overriding

I would like to know how have I do to add a field in the customer administration at system->configuration->Customer settings panel.

Have I create the system.xml file from the core and paste in the local folder with the same path?

and have I maintain all the content of the file or I can write only the portion interested?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should [create a module](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world) to hold your customizations.  Within this module [create a system.xml](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration) file that only overrides/adds what you want to your configuration section(s).