# remove store code for default store

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

The site has 2 languages: French and Dutch, represented by 2 store views.  French is the default one.  For our SEO efforts we need to have the following urls:

1. French - http://www.domain.com/category/product
2. Dutch - http://www.domain.com/nl/category/product

System -> Configuration -> Web -> Add Store Codes to URL is the all or nothing setting.
We just need to turn it off for the default store only.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have developed an extension that allows you to hide the default store code directly from Magento Admin.

[image]

More information here: https://github.com/jreinke/magento-hide-default-store-code

Answer (score 0):

After short investigation I found that it is possible, but it is not programmatically enabled by default.

Take a look in this file from *app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml*:

```
// around line 1092 - magento v1.6.2.0
<use_store translate="label">
    <label>Add Store Code to Urls</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_store</backend_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</use_store>
```

This three lines indicates configuration visibility in current scope

```
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
```

Unfortunately you cannot simply change those values to 1, because magento after upgrade overwrites all core files from *app/core* and you will lose all setup that was done there.

You can override config by overriding module system. Check:  [How to override a Magento administration panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523853/how-to-override-a-magento-administration-panel)

I am a new with Magento world. Perhaps there's an easier way to do it

Greetings
Marcin

Comment: This option - if exists by web interface - must be well-hidden. Summarizing I have no idea why Magento disabled it by default.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I think you have misunderstood my question, I want to enable 'Add store code to url' in the admin, but in the web site, I want the default store url to not have the language code , like domain.com/category/product . I want the store code only for the other languages in the store , for example : domain.com/nl/category/product.

Hope I could get a solution

Comment: @maximus69 This will **NOT** change admin URL but customer (frontend, website). Check it by your self. Change for a while config from *app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml*, set values to 1. Next please log into admin panel, go to *System -> Configuration -> Web*, switch website by *"Current Configuration Scope"* drop-down placed in left top corner of browser site. Option *"Add Store Code to Urls"* should be available for all websites and stores. Please report if this is what you are looking for. Greetz

Comment: I just checked, it looks good except that when i login (as a customer) I get an error "The page isn't redirecting properly", anything else I could do?

Comment: I have not received such an error on clear Magento install. Maybe clear cache, reindex data or play with *"Use Web Server Rewrites"*.

Comment: I've cleared the cache and tried the 'user web server rewrites' also, but the issue still remains..

Comment: You are using magento 1.5.x? I am using 1.6.x. I suggest to do a simple test. Install fresh Magento 1.5 and/or 1.6 and test if error still occurs. Tomorrow I'll check version 1.5 on my own.

Comment: Magento 1.5.1.0 works too. So probably yours Magento is broken.

Comment: I am using magento v.1.3.2.4, will upgrade to version 1.6 locally and try, will update you soon..